# Recyclerview: la lista se desplaza cuando se toca un botón dentro de un item

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

Mediante volley hago el parseo de la información para agregar a una lista y a su vez, agregarlo al recyclerview. Dentro de cada item hay un botón que realiza una función pero cuando se da clic en este botón el recyclerview se desplaza hacia arriba y se pierde el item al que se dio clic.

Tengo algo como esto:

```
DataLife dataLife = new DataLife();
dataLife.folio = folio;
dataLife.imagen = imagen;
data.add(dataLife);

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
lifeAdapter = new LifeAdapter(getActivity(), data);
rv.setAdapter(lifeAdapter);
```

Comment: Agrega  a tu pregunta el codigo del evento clic.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el evento Onclick del boton?

Comment: Lo que hago es tomar los datos del elemento que se seleccionó, algo como esto: data.get(position) y mediante ese botón lo envío a un endpoint. Después coloco un icono u otro dependiendo del contenido del json y agrego una cadena a un textview

Comment: @AlejandroCasablancas es importante seas especifico en tu pregunta y agregues datos necesarios para la solución de tu pregunta, Einer y David sugieren agregues el método onClick porque es importante para saber que sucede en este caso, agrégalo a tu pregunta por favor :). Aprovecho para invitarte a realizar el [tour] y conozcas el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Muy importante revisar [ask] para conocer como realizar adecuadamente una pregunta, saludos y suerte!

Comment: Es muy extenso y no cabe, me limita los caracteres.